# Extracting HTML content from a search page using Beautiful Soup with Python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get some hotels info from booking.com using Beautiful Soup. I need to get certain info from all the accomodations in Spain. This is the search url:

https://www.booking.com/searchresults.html?aid=304142&label=gen173nr-1DCAEoggJCAlhYSDNYBGigAYgBAZgBMbgBB8gBDNgBA-gBAfgBApICAXmoAgM&sid=1677838e3fc7c26577ea908d40ad5faf&class_interval=1&dest_id=197&dest_type=country&dtdisc=0&from_sf=1&group_adults=2&group_children=0&inac=0&index_postcard=0&label_click=undef&no_rooms=1&oos_flag=0&postcard=0&raw_dest_type=country&room1=A%2CA&sb_price_type=total&search_selected=1&src_elem=sb&ss=Spain&ss_all=0&ss_raw=spain&ssb=empty&sshis=0&order=popularity

When I inspect an accomodation in the result page using the developer tools it says that this is the tag to search:

```html
<a class="hotel_name_link url" href="&#10;/hotel/es/aran-la-abuela.html?label=gen173nr-1DCAEoggJCAlhYSDNYBGigAYgBAZgBMbgBB8gBDNgBA-gBAfgBApICAXmoAgM;sid=1677838e3fc7c26577ea908d40ad5faf;ucfs=1;srpvid=b4980e34f6e50017;srepoch=1514167274;room1=A%2CA;hpos=1;hapos=1;dest_type=country;dest_id=197;srfid=198499756e07f93263596e1640823813c2ee4fe1X1;from=searchresults&#10;;highlight_room=#hotelTmpl" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
<span class="sr-hotel__name
" data-et-click="
customGoal:YPNdKNKNKZJUESUPTOdJDUFYQC:1
">
Hotel Spa Aran La Abuela
</span>
<span class="invisible_spoken">Opens in new window</span>
</a>
```

This is my Python code:

```
def init_BeautifulSoup():
    global page, soup
    page= requests.get("https://www.booking.com/searchresults.html?aid=304142&label=gen173nr-1DCAEoggJCAlhYSDNYBGigAYgBAZgBMbgBB8gBDNgBA-gBAfgBApICAXmoAgM&sid=1677838e3fc7c26577ea908d40ad5faf&class_interval=1&dest_id=197&dest_type=country&dtdisc=0&from_sf=1&group_adults=2&group_children=0&inac=0&index_postcard=0&label_click=undef&no_rooms=1&oos_flag=0&postcard=0&raw_dest_type=country&room1=A%2CA&sb_price_type=total&search_selected=1&src_elem=sb&ss=Spain&ss_all=0&ss_raw=spain&ssb=empty&sshis=0&order=popularity")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')


def get_spain_accomodations():
    global accomodations
    accomodations = soup.find_all(class_="hotel_name_link.url")
```

But when I run the code and print the accomodations variable it outputs a pair of brackets ([]). Then I printed the soup object and I realized that the parsed HTML is very different from the one I see in the developer tools in Chrome, that's why the soup object cant find the class "hotel_name_link.url"

What's going on?

Comment: Perhaps javascript is modifying the page?

Comment: what can I do to solve it?

Comment: save data in .html file and open in browser - maybe you see useful information like warning for bots/scripts.

Comment: you have wrong class - there is no dot in HTML - `class_="hotel_name_link url"`. But maybe you many have to use `requests.Session()` to get cookies.

Comment: I think something wrong with your link in requests.get(). I saved response body and open in browser and the page said that searching failed

Comment: I think your problem is you didn't encode GET parameter, try to encode GET parameter and request again

Comment: I can get data only if I remove `dest_type=country` and use url with `searchresults.pl.html` - `pl` means Polish lanugage (my native language). With `es` or `en-GB` I always get page with new form which ask for more details.

Comment: I guess what you're finding is content of that particular class and what you're looking for is the link assigned to the <a> . You should scrap the page for 'href' of the <a>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript is modifying the page after it loads. So, when you use `page.content`, it gives you the HTML content of the page before JS modifies the page.

You can use [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to render the JS content. After the page loads, you can use `driver.page_souce` to get the page source after JS modifies it and pass it to BeautifulSoup.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

def get_page(url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'h1')))
    except TimeoutException:
        print('Page timed out.')
        return None
    page = driver.page_source
    return page

def init_BeautifulSoup():
    global page, soup
    page = get_page('your-url')
    # handle the case where page may be None
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
```

**EDIT:**

You'll need to change one thing here.

What the part `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'h1')))` does is that it makes the driver wait explicitly until the element is located on the webpage that we specify or throws `TimeoutException` after the delay time you specify (I've used 10 seconds).

I've just provided you with an example. You need to find out the element on the loaded page that is not present before the execution of the JavaScript and replace it here: `(By.TAG_NAME, 'h1')`

You can do this by inspecting elements after the page is loaded and checking whether the element exists or not in the HTML code of the page source.

Instead of `By.TAG_NAME`, you can use any of the following according to your requirement: `ID`, `NAME`, `CLASS_NAME`, `CSS_SELECTOR`, `XPATH`.

Comment: @IanSpitz, Sorry, I forgot to add some explanation earlier. Check the edit. It should work after the changes you do.