# Get specific informaion from html code

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, soundcloud

The idea is to collect all soundcloud users' id's (not names) who posted tracks that first letter is e.g. "f" in the period in our case of "past year".

I used filters on soundcloud and got results in the next URL: https://soundcloud.com/search/sounds?q=f&filter.created_at=last_year&filter.genre_or_tag=hip-hop%20%26%20rap

I found the first user's id ("wavey-hefner") in the follow line of html code: 
`<a class="sound__coverArt" href="/wavey-hefner/foreign" draggable="true">`

I want to get every user's id from the whole html.

My code is:

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = requests.get("https://soundcloud.com/search/sounds?q=f& filter.created_at=last_year&filter.genre_or_tag=hip-hop%20%26%20rap")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')
for id in soup.findAll("a", {"class" : "sound_coverArt"}):
    print (id.get('href'))
```

It returns nothing :(

Comment: try to debug it by replace id.get with a string

Comment: Make sure you use two underscores in `"class": "sound__coverArt"` -- right now you just have 1

Comment: @ChristianSantos I tried to run with 2 and it still returns nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page is rendered in JavaScript. You can use Selenium to render it, first install Selenium:

```
pip3 install selenium
```

Then get a driver e.g. https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads (if you are on Windows or Mac you can get a headless version of Chrome - Canary if you like) put the driver in your path.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
url = ('https://soundcloud.com/search/sounds?q=f& filter.created_at=last_year&filter.genre_or_tag=hip-hop%20%26%20rap')
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
# To make it load more scroll to the bottom of the page (repeat if you want to)
browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
time.sleep(5)
html_source = browser.page_source
browser.quit()

soup =   BeautifulSoup(html_source, 'html.parser')
for id in soup.findAll("a", {"class" : "sound__coverArt"}):
    print (id.get('href'))
```

Outputs:

```
/tee-grizzley/from-the-d-to-the-a-feat-lil-yachty
/empire/fat-joe-remy-ma-all-the-way-up-ft-french-montana
/tee-grizzley/first-day-out
/21savage/feel-it
/pluggedsoundz/famous-dex-geek-1
/rodshootinbirds/fairytale-x-rod-da-god
/chancetherapper/finish-line-drown-feat-t-pain-kirk-franklin-eryn-allen-kane-noname
/alkermith/future-low-life-ft-the-weeknd-evol
/javon-woodbridge/fabolous-slim-thick
/hamburgerhelper/feed-the-streets-prod-dequexatron-1000
/rob-neal-139819089/french-montana-lockjaw-remix-ft-gucci-mane-kodak-black
/pluggedsoundz/famous-dex-energy
/ovosoundradiohits/future-ft-drake-used-to-this
/pluggedsoundz/famous
/a-boogie-wit-da-hoodie/fucking-kissing-feat-chris-brown
/wavey-hefner/foreign
/jalensantoy/foreplay
/yvng_swag/fall-in-luv
/rich-the-kid/intro-prod-by-lab-cook
/empire/fat-joe-remy-ma-money-showers-feat-ty-dolla-ign
```

Comment: This works. But I'd suggest using [explicit wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html), instead of `time.sleep()` as it will be faster

Comment: @BohdanS you can [refer this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48004110/7832176) for using explicit wait.