# BeautifulSoup4 Not detecting Select tag

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to learn web scraping, I need to get the all the select tags in the web page. But they are not getting detected by BeautifulSoup4. Here is my code in python 3

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml 

req = Request('https://www.nseindia.com/', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, "lxml")
#print(soup.find("select", id="QuoteSearch"))
#print(soup.find_all("div", {'class':'equity'}))
print(soup.find("select"))
```

Output

```
None
```

Also, I am planning to make my script choose a certain option in the select tag. I would love it if someone could tell me how this can be done. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you'll have to use `selenium`

Comment: It doesn't seem as if there are any select tags in the webpage?

Comment: At the very top of the webpage there a select tag. I need to make my script select Equity Derivatives.

Comment: Adam I havent heard of selenium, I'll look into it.

Comment: @trollster Is there a way to make the script take in the final html after everything is loaded?

Comment: Go for selenium. It will solve your issue. The very portion you are interested in are javascript encrypted

Comment: @AbhishekGangadhar, `Requests` can't handle JavaScript driven pages. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48004110/7832176). It's a similar question. I've explained how to use `Selenium`.

Comment: for javascript rendered pages you cant use beautifulsoup directly .First use selenium and then using it you can get html source code after that apply beautifulsoup